# HTML Agility pack throw in "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" Exception

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm going to parsing a website content Website HTML Content. I use follow codes:

```
        private async void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string address = "http://www.iiees.ac.ir/fa/eqcatalog";
        loadButton.IsEnabled = false;

        //string htmlCode = await DownloadStringAsync(address, Encoding.UTF8);
        string htmlCode = await GetDataAsync(address, Encoding.UTF8);
        paragraph1.Inlines.Add(new Run(htmlCode));
        loadButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }


    private async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string address, Encoding encoding)
    {
        string htmlCode = await DownloadStringAsync(address, encoding);
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
        foreach (var table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            if (table.Id == "CatalogForm")
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {
                    if (row.Attributes.Any(a => a.Value == "hidecircle"))
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode td in row.SelectNodes("TD"))
                        {
                            foreach (HtmlNode option in td.SelectNodes("option"))
                            {
                                options.Add(option.InnerText);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        options.ForEach(str => sb.AppendLine(str));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

But throw in "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" exception.

For more information, I upload my project [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D4686A2B7F008810!510&authkey=!AGdlURXOJuqiCiU&ithint=file%2Czip).

[Download project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D4686A2B7F008810!510&authkey=!AGdlURXOJuqiCiU&ithint=file%2Czip)

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample from your code, and I found the following:

1. I am not particularly familiar with `xpath`, but seems it is case sensitive. Searching for "TD" will return nothing, while searching for "td" will.
2. SelectNodes will return null whenever nothing was found, and a foreach that depends on it will always throw an exception. So it is better to check whether the result of SelectNodes is not null before trying to loop over it.

---

```
  foreach (HtmlNode td in row.SelectNodes("td"))
    {
        var ops = td.SelectNodes("option");

        if (ops != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode option in ops)
            {
                options.Add(option.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
```